# compare one list to another and show the result

Tags: python, binary, compare, python-3.4

I have to make some to convert hex to binary, and them compare to some list and show the results.

The part of conversion I already did, but the part to compare I am struggling with.

```
bitmap = input("inform your bitmap: ")
h_size = len(bitmap)*4
bitmap = (bin(int(bitmap,16))[2:]).zfill(h_size)
str_bitmap = str(bitmap)
for a,b in enumerate(str_bitmap):
    print(a,b)
```

The output:

```
inform your bitmap: 7a
0 0
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 0
6 1
7 0
```

So I want to get, when is 1, the enumerate and compare to another list, like in this case:

```
1,2,3,4,6   (the 0,5,7 don't go because is 0)
```

and would check from a list and bring results like:

```
1 = bakery
2 = banana
3 = car
4 = house
5 = keyboard
6 = mouse
```

and the final result would be:

```
bakery, banana, car, house, mouse
```

What is the way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could have the strings in a dict and then use list comprehension to pick them up if `b == '1'`:

```
>>> str_bitmap = '01111010'
>>> names = {1:'bakery', 2:'banana', 3:'car', 4:'house', 5:'keyboard', 6:'mouse'}
>>> [names[a] for a, b in enumerate(str_bitmap) if b == '1']
['bakery', 'banana', 'car', 'house', 'mouse']
```

Answer (score 0):

You print the corresponding list item based on the current enumerated binary digit:

```
bitmap = input("inform your bitmap: ")
h_size = len(bitmap)*4
bitmap = (bin(int(bitmap, 16))[2:]).zfill(h_size)
str_bitmap = str(bitmap)
items = [
    "",
    "bakery",   #1
    "banana",   #2
    "car",      #3
    "house",    #4
    "keyboard", #5
    "mouse"     #6
]
for i,b in enumerate(str_bitmap):
    if b == "1":
        print("  {} = {}".format(i, items[i]))
```

Output given `"7a"` as input:

```
1 = bakery
2 = banana
3 = car   
4 = house 
6 = mouse
```